# how to flatten a nested object using javascript

Tags: javascript

```
var obj = {
a: {
    aa: {
        aaa: {
            aaaa: "a"
        }
    }
},
b: {
    bb: {
        bbb: "b"
    }
  }
}
flatten(obj)
//=>[["a","b"],["aa","bb"],["aaa","bbb"],["aaaa"]]
```

This is interesting question,my friend says BFS or DFS can be able to solve the problem,but I can't

Comment: So what did you try?

Comment: Please [edit] to add meaningful code and a problem description here. Posting a [mcve] that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use recursion and keep a level counter, on each step of recursion add keys to the result array. For this you have to check if an array already exists at that level then concatenate to that array.

```js
var obj = {
a: {
aa: {
    aaa: {
        aaaa: "a"
    }
}
},
b: {
bb: {
    bbb: "b"
}
  }
}
var result = [];
function flatten(obj, level){
   var keys = Object.keys(obj);
   result[level] = result[level] !== undefined ? result[level].concat(keys) : keys;

   keys.forEach(x => typeof obj[x] === 'object' && flatten(obj[x], level + 1));
}

flatten(obj, 0);
console.log(result);
```